# how to decrypt the track data using 3DES DUKPT

Tags: encryption, cryptography, ansi, 3des, credit-card-track-data

I am working with a piece of hardware that encrypts data using Triple Des DUKPT (ANSI Standard). I have access to the KSN and the encrypted track2 data from this I need the data to be decrypted.
Can somebody help me by providing the DUKPT C++ code/library?

Regards

user1

Answer (score 2):

I started this quest a long time ago here: [Decrypting DUKPT Encrypted Track Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11750036/decrypting-dukpt-encrypted-track-data)

Here is a .Net implementation: https://github.com/sgbj/Dukpt.NET

Here is a java implementation from jPOS: https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/java/org/jpos/security/jceadapter/JCESecurityModule.java#L1843-1856

Good luck!